# How to see raid array in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have just setup Windows 2012 Server Standard on an HP DL380 Gen 9. I have a raid 1 array with 2 drives and a raid 5 array with 4 drives. The drives are all 600GB SAS. This Server 2012 installation will be running Hyper-V and then 2 VMs will be installed, both running Server 2012.

In the server software these raid arrays are setup fine and recognised. I installed the OS successfully to the raid 1 array.

My question is, when I boot to the Server 2012 environment I can see the raid 5 array in disk management but I can't access it with a right click to define a volume. What is the best method to set this up? I'd like to install my VMs on there. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Raid array not visible]

I understand that I also need to define it as a SAN for the VMs later on too, maybe this needs doing now, if so how?

Comment: Is the RAID 5 disk online in Disk Management? Is the disk initialized? Please post a screenshot of the disk in question in Disk Management.

Comment: You couldn't post a screenshot? It's hard to see the disk status in that photo. It looks like it's offline. Have you tried to set it online?

Comment: @joeqwerty - I have added a screenshot to the original posts, thanks. Seems I may have done it now by running DISKPART, I'll update this with a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disk is offline. You need to right-click on the disk itself (the square to the left of the unallocated space) and set the disk to online.